Error when trying to parse robot_description in YAML format
I've tried to follow the Articulated Robotics tutorial on ros2_control (in the real world) but I'm stuck when launching the package. Apparently, it's trying to parse the robot_description parameter used for the controller_manager in yaml format and giving me an error (this is the output):
    [INFO] [launch]: All log files can be found below /home/flamethrower/.ros/log/2024-08-12-14-38-53-601886-robot-3133
    [INFO] [launch]: Default logging verbosity is set to INFO
    Task exception was never retrieved
    future: <Task finished name='Task-2' coro=<LaunchService._process_one_event() done, defined at /opt/ros/foxy/lib/python3.8/site-packages/launch/launch_service.py:226> exception=TypeError('Unable to parse the value of parameter robot_description as yaml. If the parameter is meant to be a string, try wrapping it in launch_ros.parameter_descriptions.ParameterValue(value, value_type=str)')>
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/opt/ros/foxy/lib/python3.8/site-packages/launch_ros/utilities/evaluate_parameters.py", line 78, in evaluate_parameter_dict
        yaml_evaluated_value = yaml.safe_load(evaluated_value)
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/yaml/__init__.py", line 162, in safe_load
        return load(stream, SafeLoader)
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/yaml/__init__.py", line 114, in load
        return loader.get_single_data()
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/yaml/constructor.py", line 49, in get_single_data
        node = self.get_single_node()
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/yaml/composer.py", line 36, in get_single_node
        document = self.compose_document()
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/yaml/composer.py", line 58, in compose_document
        self.get_event()
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/yaml/parser.py", line 118, in get_event
        self.current_event = self.state()
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/yaml/parser.py", line 193, in parse_document_end
        token = self.peek_token()
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/yaml/scanner.py", line 129, in peek_token
        self.fetch_more_tokens()
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/yaml/scanner.py", line 258, in fetch_more_tokens
        raise ScannerError("while scanning for the next token", None,
    yaml.scanner.ScannerError: while scanning for the next token
    found character '\t' that cannot start any token
      in "<unicode string>", line 24, column 1:
            
        ^
    
    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
    
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/opt/ros/foxy/lib/python3.8/site-packages/launch/launch_service.py", line 228, in _process_one_event
        await self.__process_event(next_event)
      File "/opt/ros/foxy/lib/python3.8/site-packages/launch/launch_service.py", line 248, in __process_event
        visit_all_entities_and_collect_futures(entity, self.__context))
      File "/opt/ros/foxy/lib/python3.8/site-packages/launch/utilities/visit_all_entities_and_collect_futures_impl.py", line 45, in visit_all_entities_and_collect_futures
        futures_to_return += visit_all_entities_and_collect_futures(sub_entity, context)
      File "/opt/ros/foxy/lib/python3.8/site-packages/launch/utilities/visit_all_entities_and_collect_futures_impl.py", line 45, in visit_all_entities_and_collect_futures
        futures_to_return += visit_all_entities_and_collect_futures(sub_entity, context)
      File "/opt/ros/foxy/lib/python3.8/site-packages/launch/utilities/visit_all_entities_and_collect_futures_impl.py", line 45, in visit_all_entities_and_collect_futures
        futures_to_return += visit_all_entities_and_collect_futures(sub_entity, context)
      [Previous line repeated 3 more times]
      File "/opt/ros/foxy/lib/python3.8/site-packages/launch/utilities/visit_all_entities_and_collect_futures_impl.py", line 38, in visit_all_entities_and_collect_futures
        sub_entities = entity.visit(context)
      File "/opt/ros/foxy/lib/python3.8/site-packages/launch/action.py", line 108, in visit
        return self.execute(context)
      File "/opt/ros/foxy/lib/python3.8/site-packages/launch_ros/actions/node.py", line 444, in execute
        self._perform_substitutions(context)
      File "/opt/ros/foxy/lib/python3.8/site-packages/launch_ros/actions/node.py", line 399, in _perform_substitutions
        evaluated_parameters = evaluate_parameters(context, self.__parameters)
      File "/opt/ros/foxy/lib/python3.8/site-packages/launch_ros/utilities/evaluate_parameters.py", line 164, in evaluate_parameters
        output_params.append(evaluate_parameter_dict(context, param))
      File "/opt/ros/foxy/lib/python3.8/site-packages/launch_ros/utilities/evaluate_parameters.py", line 80, in evaluate_parameter_dict
        raise TypeError(
    TypeError: Unable to parse the value of parameter robot_description as yaml. If the parameter is meant to be a string, try wrapping it in launch_ros.parameter_descriptions.ParameterValue(value, value_type=str)

These are my files currently:
robot.launch.py:
import os

from ament_index_python.packages import get_package_share_directory


from launch import LaunchDescription
from launch.actions import IncludeLaunchDescription, TimerAction
from launch.launch_description_sources import PythonLaunchDescriptionSource
from launch.substitutions import Command
from launch.actions import RegisterEventHandler
from launch.event_handlers import OnProcessStart

from launch_ros.actions import Node



def generate_launch_description():


    # Include the robot_state_publisher launch file, provided by our own package. Force sim time to be enabled
    # !!! MAKE SURE YOU SET THE PACKAGE NAME CORRECTLY !!!

    package_name='robot' #<--- CHANGE ME

    rsp = IncludeLaunchDescription(
                PythonLaunchDescriptionSource([os.path.join(
                    get_package_share_directory(package_name),'launch','rsp.launch.py'
                )]), launch_arguments={'use_sim_time': 'false', 'use_ros2_control': 'true'}.items()
    )

    robot_description = Command(['ros2 param get --hide-type /robot_state_publisher robot_description'])
    controller_params_file = os.path.join(get_package_share_directory(package_name),'config','my_controllers.yaml')
    
    controller_manager = Node(
        package="controller_manager",
        executable="ros2_control_node",
        parameters=[{'robot_description': robot_description},
                    controller_params_file]
    )
    
    delayed_controller_manager = TimerAction(period=3.0, actions=[controller_manager])
    
    diff_drive_spawner = Node(
        package="controller_manager",
        executable="spawner.py",
        arguments=["diff_cont"],
    )
    
    delayed_diff_drive_spawner = RegisterEventHandler(
        event_handler=OnProcessStart(
            target_action=controller_manager,
            on_start=[diff_drive_spawner],
        )
    )

    joint_broad_spawner = Node(
        package="controller_manager",
        executable="spawner.py",
        arguments=["joint_broad"],
    )
    
    delayed_joint_broad_spawner = RegisterEventHandler(
        event_handler=OnProcessStart(
            target_action=controller_manager,
            on_start=[joint_broad_spawner],
        )
    )



    # Launch them all!
    return LaunchDescription([
        rsp,
        delayed_controller_manager,
        delayed_diff_drive_spawner,
        delayed_joint_broad_spawner
    ])

rsp.launch.py:
import os

from ament_index_python.packages import get_package_share_directory

from launch import LaunchDescription
from launch.substitutions import LaunchConfiguration, Command
from launch.actions import DeclareLaunchArgument
from launch_ros.actions import Node

import xacro


def generate_launch_description():

    use_sim_time = LaunchConfiguration('use_sim_time')
    use_ros2_control = LaunchConfiguration('use_ros2_control')

    # Process the URDF file
    pkg_path = os.path.join(get_package_share_directory('robot'))
    xacro_file = os.path.join(pkg_path,'description','robot.urdf.xacro')
    # robot_description_config = xacro.process_file(xacro_file).toxml()
    robot_description_config = Command(['xacro ', xacro_file, ' use_ros2_control:=', use_ros2_control, ' sim_mode:=', use_sim_time])
    
    # Create a robot_state_publisher node
    params = {'robot_description': robot_description_config, 'use_sim_time': use_sim_time}
    node_robot_state_publisher = Node(
        package='robot_state_publisher',
        executable='robot_state_publisher',
        output='screen',
        parameters=[params]
    )

    # Launch!
    return LaunchDescription([
        DeclareLaunchArgument(
            'use_sim_time',
            default_value='false',
            description='Use sim time if true'),
        DeclareLaunchArgument(
            'use_ros2_control',
            default_value='true',
            description='Use ros2_control if true'),

        node_robot_state_publisher
    ])

robot.urdf.xacro:
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<robot xmlns:xacro="http://www.ros.org/wiki/xacro"  name="robot">

    <xacro:arg name="use_ros2_control" default="true"/>
    <xacro:arg name="sim_mode" default="false"/>

    <xacro:include filename="robot_core.xacro" />
    <xacro:include filename="ros2_control.xacro"/>
    <xacro:include filename="lidar.xacro"/>

</robot>

ros2_control.xacro:
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<robot xmlns:xacro="http://www.ros.org/wiki/xacro">

    <ros2_control name="RobotSystem" type="system">
        <hardware>
            <plugin>diffdrive_arduino/DiffDriveArduino</plugin>
            <param name="left_wheel_name">FL_wheel_joint RL_wheel_joint</param>
            <param name="right_wheel_name">FR_wheel_joint RR_wheel_joint</param>
            <param name="loop_rate">30</param>
            <param name="device">/dev/ttyUSB0</param>
            <param name="baud_rate">57600</param>
            <param name="timeout">1000</param>
            <param name="enc_counts_per_rev">3450</param>
        </hardware>
        <joint name="FL_wheel_joint">
            <command_interface name="velocity">
                <param name="min">-10</param>
                <param name="max">10</param>
            </command_interface>
            <state_interface name="velocity"/>
            <state_interface name="position"/>
        </joint>
        <joint name="FR_wheel_joint">
            <command_interface name="velocity">
                <param name="min">-10</param>
                <param name="max">10</param>
            </command_interface>
            <state_interface name="velocity"/>
            <state_interface name="position"/>
        </joint>
        <joint name="RL_wheel_joint">
            <command_interface name="velocity">
                <param name="min">-10</param>
                <param name="max">10</param>
            </command_interface>
            <state_interface name="velocity"/>
            <state_interface name="position"/>
        </joint>
        <joint name="RR_wheel_joint">
            <command_interface name="velocity">
                <param name="min">-10</param>
                <param name="max">10</param>
            </command_interface>
            <state_interface name="velocity"/>
            <state_interface name="position"/>
        </joint>
    </ros2_control>
    
    <!--
    <ros2_control name="GazeboSystem" type="system">
        <hardware>
            <plugin>gazebo_ros2_control/GazeboSystem</plugin>
        </hardware>
        <joint name="FL_wheel_joint">
            <command_interface name="velocity">
                <param name="min">-10</param>
                <param name="max">10</param>
            </command_interface>
            <state_interface name="velocity"/>
            <state_interface name="position"/>
        </joint>
        <joint name="FR_wheel_joint">
            <command_interface name="velocity">
                <param name="min">-10</param>
                <param name="max">10</param>
            </command_interface>
            <state_interface name="velocity"/>
            <state_interface name="position"/>
        </joint>
        <joint name="RL_wheel_joint">
            <command_interface name="velocity">
                <param name="min">-10</param>
                <param name="max">10</param>
            </command_interface>
            <state_interface name="velocity"/>
            <state_interface name="position"/>
        </joint>
        <joint name="RR_wheel_joint">
            <command_interface name="velocity">
                <param name="min">-10</param>
                <param name="max">10</param>
            </command_interface>
            <state_interface name="velocity"/>
            <state_interface name="position"/>
        </joint>
    </ros2_control>
    -->
    
    <gazebo>
        <plugin filename="libgazebo_ros2_control.so" name="gazebo_ros2_control">
            <parameters>$(find robot)/config/my_controllers.yaml</parameters>
        </plugin>
    </gazebo>

</robot>

robot_core.xacro:
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<robot xmlns:xacro="http://www.ros.org/wiki/xacro">

    <xacro:include filename="inertial_macros.xacro"/>
    
    <xacro:property name="chassis_length" value="0.35"/>
    <xacro:property name="chassis_width" value="0.35"/>
    <xacro:property name="chassis_height" value="1.4"/>
    <xacro:property name="chassis_mass" value="30"/>
    <xacro:property name="wheel_radius" value="0.05"/>
    <xacro:property name="wheel_thickness" value="0.01"/>
    <xacro:property name="wheel_mass" value="0.01"/>
    <!--
    <xacro:property name="wheel_offset_x" value="0.226"/>
    <xacro:property name="wheel_offset_y" value="0.1485"/>
    <xacro:property name="wheel_offset_z" value="0.01"/>
    -->

    <material name="gray">
        <color rgba="0.3 0.3 0.3 1"/>
    </material>
    
    <material name="black">
        <color rgba="0 0 0 1"/>
    </material>
    
    <material name="blue">
        <color rgba="0 0 0.6 1"/>
    </material>
    
    <link name="base_link">
    
    </link>

    <joint name="chassis_joint" type="fixed">
        <parent link="base_link"/>
        <child link="chassis"/>
        <origin xyz="-0.1 0 0"/>
        </joint>
        
    <link name="chassis">
        <visual>
            <origin xyz="0.175 0 0.715"/>
            <geometry>
                <box size="0.35 0.35 1.4"/>
            </geometry>
            <material name="gray"/>
        </visual>
        <collision>
            <origin xyz="0.175 0 0.715"/>
            <geometry>
                <box size="0.35 0.35 1.4"/>
            </geometry>
        </collision>
        <xacro:inertial_box mass="1" x="0.35" y="0.35" z="1.4">
            <origin xyz="0.2 0 0.075" rpy="0 0 0"/>
        </xacro:inertial_box>
    </link>
    
    <gazebo reference="chassis">
        <material>Gazebo/Gray</material>
    </gazebo>
    
    <joint name="FL_wheel_joint" type="continuous">
        <parent link="base_link"/>
        <child link="FL_wheel"/>
        <origin xyz="0.225 0.185 0.05" rpy="-${pi/2} 0 0"/>
        <axis xyz="0 0 1"/>
    </joint>
    
    <link name="FL_wheel">
        <visual>
            <geometry>
                <cylinder radius="0.05" length="0.02"/>
            </geometry>
            <material name="black"/>
        </visual>
        <collision>
            <geometry>
                <cylinder radius="0.05" length="0.02"/>
            </geometry>
        </collision>
        <xacro:inertial_cylinder mass="0.1" length="0.02" radius="0.05">
            <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
        </xacro:inertial_cylinder>
    </link>
    
    <gazebo reference="FL_wheel">
        <material>Gazebo/Black</material>
    </gazebo>

    <joint name="FR_wheel_joint" type="continuous">
        <parent link="base_link"/>
        <child link="FR_wheel"/>
        <origin xyz="0.225 -0.185 0.05" rpy="${pi/2} 0 0"/>
        <axis xyz="0 0 1"/>
    </joint>
    
    <link name="FR_wheel">
        <visual>
            <geometry>
                <cylinder radius="0.05" length="0.02"/>
            </geometry>
            <material name="black"/>
        </visual>
        <collision>
            <geometry>
                <cylinder radius="0.05" length="0.02"/>
            </geometry>
        </collision>
        <xacro:inertial_cylinder mass="0.1" length="0.02" radius="0.05">
            <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
        </xacro:inertial_cylinder>
    </link>
    
    <gazebo reference="FR_wheel">
        <material>Gazebo/Black</material>
    </gazebo>
    
    <joint name="RL_wheel_joint" type="continuous">
        <parent link="base_link"/>
        <child link="RL_wheel"/>
        <origin xyz="-0.075 0.185 0.05" rpy="-${pi/2} 0 0"/>
        <axis xyz="0 0 1"/>
    </joint>
    
    <link name="RL_wheel">
        <visual>
            <geometry>
                <cylinder radius="0.05" length="0.02"/>
            </geometry>
            <material name="black"/>
        </visual>
        <collision>
            <geometry>
                <cylinder radius="0.05" length="0.02"/>
            </geometry>
        </collision>
        <xacro:inertial_cylinder mass="0.1" length="0.02" radius="0.05">
            <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
        </xacro:inertial_cylinder>
    </link>
    
    <gazebo reference="RL_wheel">
        <material>Gazebo/Black</material>
    </gazebo>

    <joint name="RR_wheel_joint" type="continuous">
        <parent link="base_link"/>
        <child link="RR_wheel"/>
        <origin xyz="-0.075 -0.185 0.05" rpy="${pi/2} 0 0"/>
        <axis xyz="0 0 1"/>
    </joint>
    
    <link name="RR_wheel">
        <visual>
            <geometry>
                <cylinder radius="0.05" length="0.02"/>
            </geometry>
            <material name="black"/>
        </visual>
        <collision>
            <geometry>
                <cylinder radius="0.05" length="0.02"/>
            </geometry>
        </collision>
        <xacro:inertial_cylinder mass="0.1" length="0.02" radius="0.05">
            <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
        </xacro:inertial_cylinder>
    </link>
    
    <gazebo reference="RR_wheel">
        <material>Gazebo/Black</material>
    </gazebo>

</robot>

my_controllers.yaml:
controller_manager:
  ros__parameters:
    update_rate: 30
    #use_sim_time: true

    diff_cont:
      type: diff_drive_controller/DiffDriveController

    joint_broad:
      type: joint_state_broadcaster/JointStateBroadcaster

diff_cont:
  ros__parameters:

    publish_rate: 50.0

    base_frame_id: base_link

    left_wheel_names: ["FL_wheel_joint", "RL_wheel_joint"]
    right_wheel_names: ["FR_wheel_joint", "RR_wheel_joint"]
    wheel_separation: 0.35
    wheel_radius: 0.05

    use_stamped_vel: false

    # open_loop: false    

    wheels_per_side: 2

I've now confirmed that launching the articubot_one package does work, so it's definitely something about my files (most likely the description ones, as the launch files are identical). My guess would be the fact that it has 4 wheels, but xacro recognizes the files as valid and removing the second wheel names in ros2_control.xacro doesn't change the error.

The issue was that I'd used tabs instead of spaces in my ros2_control.xacro file, which are not supported in yaml format.

I think it's unhappy with this line in your robot.launch.py:
robot_description = Command(['ros2 param get --hide-type /robot_state_publisher robot_description'])

You should probably be generating the robot_description from an Xacro command rather than getting it from an external param.
You may also try to run this node through an OpaqueFunction so that you can evaluate the parameter at launch time.

But why does this work in the tutorial? Is it like a new update? And how would I put the xacro command or the OpaqueFunction? (sorry I'm new to ROS)

I generally try to avoid running CLI commands in launch files since the launch system is so complex, but I think you can still do it if you run a Parameter.perform(context=context). Here is an example of OpaqueFunction from Universal Robots.

Sorry for taking this long, my SD card got corrupted and gave me a lot of trouble. So I noticed that in rsp.launch.py, an xacro command is used. Isn't this what's generating the robot_description?

@Flamethrower Yes, it is, it's not very Pythonic though. If your xacro ends up taking a lot of parameter inputs, it looks quite messy. I'd either recommend the xacro package which can be run directly with python commands, or the MoveItConfigsBuilder, which seems to be MoveIt's new standard (and looks quite clean).
